# generate a range of ints -- "out of local stack" [beginner]

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

`gen(N,R)`:

`R` is value between 0 and N-1, in order. 
`N`non-zero positive int. `N` will always be given.

For example: `?- genN(2,R)`. gives `R=0;R=1.` I implemented like this, but it has "out of local static error":

```
gen(X,0).
gen(X,R) :-
  gen(X,R1),
  R is R1+1,
  R<X,       % why this line
  R>=0.      % and this line can't keep the range successfully?
```

Result:

```
 ?- genN2(3,R).  
    R = 0 ;
    R = 1 ;
    R = 2 ;
    ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why your program does not terminate, use a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). To this end, we will insert some extra goals **`false`** that help to understand why the goals you added are irrelevant.  If this resulting fragment does not terminate, then your original program does not terminate either. As you can see, there is not much happening in that part. In fact your program will terminate **never**.

```
gen(_X,0) :- false.
gen(X,R) :-
  gen(X,R1), false,
  R is R1+1,
  R<X,
  R>=0.
```

(There are some more issues: your definition would be true also for a goal like `gen(-1,0)` which is probably not what you intended.)

The best way to solve this all at once is to use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) instead of the more complex to handle `(is)/2` or simply to use `between/3`:

```
gen(N0, R) :-
   N1 is N0-1,
   between(0, N1, R).
```